# How can i calculate density of every centroid in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

i have kmeans clustered data, and cluster centroids of the kmeans. I want to calculate density of each cluster centroid and remove the cluster of the highest cluster centroid density. I did my research, and find this formula.

[image]

N(c) is a set of neighbor cluster centroids of cluster c and should be 5
I tried to implement the algorithm but couldn't do. Can you help me implement it?

Here is my code so far:

```
df = make_blobs(n_samples=5000, n_features=15,centers=15, cluster_std=1,random_state=10)
X,y=df
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=10)
TrainData=X_train,y_train
n_clusters_sampling=10
 
kmeans2 = KMeans(n_clusters = n_clusters_sampling,random_state=10)
kmeans2.fit(X_train)
centroids = kmeans2.cluster_centers_
```

Comment: Essentially, what you want is to do a 5-nearest neighbor search for each centroid considering only the centroids from `kmeans2.cluster_centers_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is essentially a "k-nearest neighbor search" on the "new dataset" formed by the centroids. You want the 5 closest ones for each centroid and their associated distances. Fortunately, `sklearn` does have the [NearestNeighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.kneighbors) class which provides this functionality:

```py
...
centroids = kmeans2.cluster_centers_

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
nn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=6) # 6 is not a typo. Explanation below.
nn.fit(centroids)
neigh_dist, neigh_ind = nn.kneighbors(centroids, return_distance=True)
densities = [5/np.sum(neigh_dist[i,:]) for i in range(centroids.shape[0])]
print(densities)
```

Note that we are fitting the `nn` object with the same datapoints (the centroids) we are performing the queries on.
This is why `n_neighbors` is 6: for each centroid, itself will be its closest neighbor with zero distance.
The `.kneighbors()` method, when `return_distance` is set to True, (also) returns an array of distances of shape (`n`, `n_neighbors`), where `n` is the number of query points - i.e. the centroids. The *i*,*j* cell of that array tells you the distance of neighbor *j* from centroid *i*. So we take averages per row to compute the densities following the formula you are posting.

---

**Edit**: The next part of the answer addresses the OP's comment for removing the cluster of highest density.

Removing a cluster, say, `c` essentially means reassigning the cluster labels of its datapoints to the next closest centroid. So, now we have a new 1-nearest neighbor problem and we can use again the NearestNeihbors object we have created.

We perform a 2-nearest neighbor search on the "centroids dataset" for the points that were initially assigned to `c`.
The first neighbor will of course be `c`, so we keep only the second nearest neighbor.
Then we simply update the original assignment table for those datapoints with the new indices.

```py
# run k-means and get an array of initial cluster assignments.
assignments = kmeans2.predict(X_train)

# find the index of cluster to be removed
c = np.argmax(densities)

# for each point originally assigned to c, find its closest centroid.
# Again we are using the trick of searching for one more neighbor since we know
# the closest centroid of those points will be c.
nearest_centroids = nn.kneighbors(X_train[assignments==c,:], n_neighbors=2, return_distance=False)

# get the new closest cenroid (that is, the second column of the array) and make it 1D
nearest_centroids = nearest_centroids[:,1].flatten()

# simply update the initial assignment table for the specific datapoints
assignments[assignments==c] = nearest_centroids
```

The `assignments` array now does not contain the value of `c`. Note that this may leave a "hole" when plotting or doing other post-processing of the results as there will be a cluster with no points assigned to it. If you want to avoid this, simply subtract one to the indices higher than c:

```py
assignments = np.array([i-1 if i>c else i for i in assignments])
```

and if you want to remove the centroid as well:

```py
centroids = np.delete(centroids, c, axis=0) # remove row from numpy array by index
```

Comment: Note that since you only care for finding the "densest" cluster for removal, for speedup, you may only compute the `[sum(neigh_dist[i,:]) for i ... ]` - i.e. the inverse of the densities, and remove the _argmin_ cluster rather than the _argmax_. You can also omit the` ||N(c)||` factor since it is the same for all centroids. That speedup is probably negligible though

Comment: Thank you so much for your work, i finally understood, thanks to you!! Now, i found 5 cluster and their indexes that has the maximum density. Do you have any idea of how to remove that 5 cluster from my original clusters(which is n_clusters=15)?

Comment: @BerkeAtalay I have updated my answer to resolve your follow up. If you use the same strategy of "nearest neighbor search", the code should be more or less straightforward

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with Manhattan Distance
the formula is  d(p, q) = d(q,p) = Sum (|qi-pi|)

```
def ManhattanDistance(x, y):
    S = 0;
    for i in range(len(x)):
        S += abs(int(x[i])- int(y[i]))

    return S
```

and her you could get the shot distance

```
def Classify(centroieds, item):
    minimum =10000;
    for i in range(len(centroieds)):

        # Find distance from item to mean
        dis = ManhattanDistance(item, centroieds[i]);

        if (dis < minimum):
            minimum = dis;
            index = i;

    return index;
```

and her you could find the clastre that fit
and i put all the cluster in a dict

```
def FindClusters(centroieds):
    clusters = {} # Init clusters

    for i in range(200):
        item = l[i]

        # Classify item into a cluster
        index = Classify(means, item);

        # Add item to cluster
        if index in clusters.keys():
            clusters[index].append()
        else:
            clusters[index] = l[i]
            clusters[index].append(l[i])

   
    return(clusters)
```

that is not all my code it is parts of it i hope it is help.

Comment: thank you so much for that detailed answer, but when i try to run the algorithm  for my centroids[], it gives an error that says "name 'l' is not defined", I tried to fix it but i did not understand what l does in the algorithm?

Comment: l is the point you want to measure the distance between it and the centroied in my code it is a list of lists  each list is a point

Comment: thank you, but i think this is not the answer for my question, i need to implement the formula i shared. Thank you for your answer and efforts tough